# How to get the Uid of other users in a group type database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to make a recycler view that displays the current members in the group. Below I have a picture of my database, basically I have a groupId which is the uid of the creator, and under we have 3 users and some other unrelated data.

[image]

The problem is I'm not sure how to get the certain uid so that I can get their profile info like this

```
groupsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").child(groupUid);
```

I also use dynamicLinks which is set up like this

```
private void attachParameter(){
        Uri link = Uri.parse("https://y95rt.app.goo.gl/Lesn")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("groupUid", groupUid)
                .build();
        generateDynamicLink(link.toString());

    }

    private void generateDynamicLink(String link) {
        Uri dynamicLink = Uri.parse("https://y95rt.app.goo.gl")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("link", link)
                .appendQueryParameter("apn", "c.kristofer.jaxxx")
                .build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Join my group for Lesn");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dynamicLink.toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Any answers/suggestions is appreciated and is also open to changing my structure. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ProfileInfo`, and just do this:

```
Groups
  groupid
     userid
       name: userx
       email: userx@gmail.com
     userid1
       name: usery
       email: usery@gmail.com
```

then, if you have a list of names, then to retrieve try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Groups").child(groupUid);

reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(name_here).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
  String keys=datas.getKey();
   }
}
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   }
});
```

the snapshot will be at child `groupid`, then if the condition is satisfied, you will iterate and get the id of that user.

Comment: I've actually solved it and was about to write an answer. It works the same way as your answer so I'll mark it as the correct one